# I could not enter through the door so I was forced to climb .... a window

Tags: prepositions

> I could not enter through the door so I was forced to climb ... a window.

Options:

- a) in
- b) into
- c) out of
- d) between

My approach:

I am confused between *into/in*.

Reason: *Into* because *into* is used to indicate movement from outside to inside

But the answer given is *in*.

Also, between cannot be used because the sentence is not used to talk about 2 things.

Out of: I found the following meanings of *out of*. None of them correlates with my sentence.

> 1) indicating the source or derivation of something; from: 
>   a bench fashioned out of a fallen tree trunk
>
> 2) having (the thing mentioned) as a motivation: she did it out of spite.
>
> 3) from among (a number): nine times out of ten.
>
> 4) not having (a particular thing): they had run out of cash.

Can anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Checking the definition of [***into***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/into):

> 1) from the outside to the inside of; to the midst or depths of"   ⇒ *walked into the house, jumped into the lake*"

you can see that the destination is *within* something (the room or the lake in the examples).

But you cannot be *within/inside of* a window in this context.

In another context, such as:

> I fell **into** the window.

by definition 4 - (so as to strike; against"   ⇒ *to bump into a door*") this would be OK.